# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: of:

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to order my location class by it's customer name but for some reason that doesn't work. This is the  part of the query where it goes wrong:

```
columns.each {
                String searchValue = it.options['searchValue']
                String domainName = it.options['domainName']
            columns.each {
                String orderValue = it.options['order']
                String domainName = it.options['domainName']
                if (orderValue) {
                    if (domainName == 'parentName') {
                        order('parent.name', orderValue)
                    } else if(domainName == 'customer'){
                        order('customer.name', orderValue)
                    } else if (domainName == 'type') {
                        order('type.name', orderValue)
                    } else if (domainName == 'devices') {
                        orderDevice = true
                        orderDeviceValue = orderValue
                    } else if (domainName =='tags'){
                        log.info("sort by tag")
                        orderTag = true
                        orderTagValue = orderValue
                    } else if (domainName == 'description') {
                        order('description', orderValue)
                    } else {
                        order(domainName, orderValue)
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is the Location class:

```
import groovy.transform.ToString

@ToString
class Location implements Comparable<Location> {

    Company customer
    Location parent
    String name
    String description
    String objectnumber
    String address
    String zipcode
    String province
    String city
    String country
    Long longitude
    Long latitude
    Integer order
    String timezone
    AlertConfiguration alertConfiguration
    boolean deleted
    LocationType type

    static mapping = {
        order column: '`order`'
        name column: '`name`'
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        parent nullable: true
        description nullable: true, maxSize: 65535
        objectnumber nullable: true
        province nullable: true
        city nullable: true
        longitude nullable: true
        latitude nullable: true
        order nullable: true
        timezone nullable: true
        type nullable: true
        alertConfiguration nullable: true
        parent nullable: true
        address nullable: true
        zipcode nullable: true
        country nullable: true, maxSize: 3
    }

    @Override
    int compareTo(Location that) {
        if (that) {
            return this.name.compareTo(that.name)
        }
        return 0
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        return "location:"+id
    }
}
```

And this is the Company class:

```
import groovy.transform.ToString

@ToString
class Company {

    String name
    String address
    String zipcode
    String province
    String city
    String country
    String phonenumber
    String email
    String website
    String cocnumber
    String vatnumber
    String logoUrl
    boolean deleted
    Account account
    String contractholder
    String initial_contract

    static mapping = {
        email column: 'emailaddress'
        version false
    }

    static hasMany =[locations: Location]

    static constraints = {
        address nullable: true
        zipcode nullable: true, maxSize: 45
        province nullable: true
        city nullable: true
        country nullable: true, maxSize: 3
        phonenumber nullable: true, maxSize: 45
        email nullable: true, email:true
        website nullable: true
        cocnumber nullable: true
        vatnumber nullable: true
        logoUrl nullable: true, url: true
        account nullable: true
        contractholder nullable: true
        initial_contract nullable: true
    }

    Company(String name) {
        System.out.println("Company constructor " + name)
    }
}
```

I do have an Account class that is linked to the Company class as well and using that I can order on Company name just fine but for some reason ordering a Location by a customer name throws an error:

> could not resolve property: customer.name of: com.x.Location.
>   Stacktrace follows: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>     at
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
>     at
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
>     at
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   customer.name of: com.x.Location  at
>   grails.orm.PagedResultList.(PagedResultList.java:43)    at
>   grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.createPagedResultList(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:160)
>     at
>   com.x.location.LocationService.$tt__findAllByAccount(LocationService.groovy:60)
>     at
>   grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
>     at
>   grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
>     at
>   com.x.location.LocationBusinessService.$tt__list(LocationBusinessService.groovy:62)
>     at
>   grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
>     at
>   grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
>     at
>   com.x.location.LocationRestController.list(LocationRestController.groovy:29)
>     ... 6 common frames omitted

Comment: Did you add a join between the two tables in your query?

Comment: Also, when using @ToString with Domain classes, you should be adding an 'excludes' parameter that contains the field name of associations to avoid having 'lazy init' issues when calling toString on the Domain classes instances. ie. @ToString(includePackage = false, includeNames = true, excludes = ['parent', 'customer'...])

Comment: I tried doing so by doing

         createAlias('customer', 'company', Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)


but then I get this error:

Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path: customer

Comment: createAlias('customer', 'custo', Criteria.LEFT_JOIN) and then in you order code : order('custo.name', orderValue)

Comment: That still gives the same error